# ng-style with condition not working, Visibility not changing

Tags: c#, css, angularjs, styles

I'm trying to 'hide' an element if the output obtained is '0'.
I've tried the below lines of code-

```
<li ng-style="{'visibility': {{PropertyListitem[0].Parking}} ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}">
   <p>Parking</p>
</li>
```

But this isn't working, Can you guys please point me out where I'm going wrong.

A simpler way to do the same is appreciated. :)

**Compiler View:**

[image: This is the Compiler View]

Comment: Do you specifically need `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none` would also be ok? If yes, then use simple `ng-show` or `ng-hide` to toggle visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#known-issues), it has known issues when using interpolation and expressions together:

> Note: Angular directive attributes take either expressions or interpolation markup with embedded expressions. It is considered bad practice to embed interpolation markup inside an expression

and also:

> **Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice:**
>   * It increases the complexity of the markup
>   * There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because interpolation itself is a
>      directive. If another directive accesses attribute data before
>      interpolation has run, it will get the raw interpolation markup and
>      not data.
>   * It impacts performance, as interpolation adds another
>      watcher to the scope.
>   * Since this is not recommended usage, we do not
>      test for this, and changes to Angular core may break your code.

**TL;DR**: update your `ng-style` as follows:

```
ng-style="{'visibility': PropertyListitem[0].Parking ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}">
```

See small [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/7d8nVFo3O33OYdPFFtjM?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the response..:).It was very helpful..It worked for me when I equated it to 1 and then did the tertiary check.. ` ng-style="{'visibility': PropertyListitem[0].Parking === '1' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}" `

Comment: Nice! Please consider upvoting the answer if you find it good and helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
<li ng-style="{'visibility': PropertyListitem[0].Parking ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}">
   <p>Parking</p>
</li>
```

You are supposed to send an object to ng-style, not a compiled string.

Comment: Thanks for the response @user1415066 :)...It was helpful